# Update a row in oracle using OLEDB command(SSIS)

Tags: oracle, oledbcommand

I am trying to update some rows in an oracle Database, using an OLEDB Command 
but whenever i try specifying the Sql Command this is what i get

```
An OLEDB record is available. Source: "OraOLEDB" Hresult:0x80040E51 Description:
"Provider cannot derive parameter information and
 SetParameterInfo has not been called."
```

I have tried using

> "Native OLE DB\Oracle Provider for OLE
>   DB" provider

and i tried changing to

> "Native OLE DB\Microsoft OLE BD Provider for Oracle" provider

but i get the same error, please help,
I am using ssis 2008

Here is the setup : The Connection Manager is as below 
[image]

When i test it, it succeeds 
[image]

Now when i come to configuring the OLEDBCommand., I pass in the Connenction Manager
[image]

specify the command

[image]

now when i move to configure the parameters, nothing is displayed and i receive this error

[image]

thanks for the help

Comment: Could you post the source code where you are making the connection and trying to perform the update with the command object?

Comment: @Dougman I added the screenshots of how i receive the error, please check above

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under Input and Output Properties you need to add the column names under OLE DB Command Input > External columns, they will then appear in the column mappings page.

Comment: Very late to the party here, but I just discovered that spaces in the parameter name are allowed in SSIS (and even defaulted with `Column 1`, etc.), but are not recognized by the Oracle provider.