# SSIS OLEDB Command - Oracle connection won't populate parameters

Tags: oracle, ssis

I'm doing some functional examples of SSIS for our org, and creating a simple process that reads a file, does a lookup, and decides whether it needs to update or insert data. I have to manually enter them in the Inpout and Output Properties and as you can expect, things aren't working correctly.

I'm having a heck of a time getting the OLEDB command to recognize my ? parameters in my update statement.

```
 UPDATE ADMIN.SSIS_TESTING
    SET Field1 = ?
      , Field2 = ?
      , Field3 = ?
      , Field4 = ?
      , Field5 = ?
  WHERE PrimaryKey = ?
```

Now when I go in the Column Mappings tab, everything is blank. I'll add in the Input Columns manually, give them the correct MappingColumnID's, and the process still doesn't want to update those columns.

I'm also getting this text in the OLE DB Command window (Googling doesn't really give me an answer)

> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Update [99]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E51. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "OraOLEDB" Hresult: 0x80040E51 Description "The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040E51 in the message file for OraOLEDB.".

This is talking to an Oracle 12 server. I can confirm that inserts with the same data source are working. My project is set to execute as 32 bit also.

Anything else to look at?

Comment: What kind of names do you set to input columns? Apparently they shouldn't have spaces in them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168772/update-a-row-in-oracle-using-oledb-commandssis#comment66042257_5269720

Comment: I have them named identical to the fields that they're updating (Field1, Field2, etc...)